# Why does Symfony not find this route?

Tags: php, symfony

I am developing an app with Symfony 3.2.0 on a Mac OSX El Capitan and I am able to view http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/create but when I go to /category/edit/1 I get this 404 error:

```
No route found for "GET /category/edit/1"
```

Here is my CategoryController.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/categories", name="category_list")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('category/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/category/create", name="category_create")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('category/create.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/category/edit/{id}", name="category_edit")
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('category/edit.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/category/delete/{id}", name="category_delete")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

I have created the edit.html.twig file in category folder.

```
ldco2016@DCortes-MacBook-Pro-3 ~/Projects/eventcalendar $ php bin/console debug:router --env=prod                                                                    [ruby-2.2.1]
 ----------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------
  Name              Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 ----------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------
  category_list     ANY      ANY      ANY    /categories
  category_create   ANY      ANY      ANY    /category/create
  category_delete   ANY      ANY      ANY    /category/delete/{id}
  homepage          ANY      ANY      ANY    /
  event_list        ANY      ANY      ANY    /events
  event_create      ANY      ANY      ANY    /event/create
  category_edit     ANY      ANY      ANY    /event/edit/{id}
  event_delete      ANY      ANY      ANY    /event/delete/{id}
 ----------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------
```

Comment: did you clear the cache of the prod env?

Comment: @Federkun, I just did and I am getting the same error message.

Comment: what's the output of `php bin/console debug:router --env=prod`?

Comment: @Federkun, that helped tremendously. Please post it as an answer. So my looking at the router. I saw that category_edit had the path of /event/edit/{id} because in my EventController.php file which I did not post here, the editAction had a name="category_edit" instead of name="event_edit". I corrected it and problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to debug this is to run this command:

```
php bin/console debug:router --env=prod
```

This will show you all the routes with their paths, and (as in this case) see if they are been overridden by some other routes with the same name.